# Why footer page is appearing on the first one and not the others in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, page-numbers

I'm trying to setup a footer on my Word document, with page numbering.

The document has only 5 pages

First page and second page are appearing on the **footer setup** as you can see.

[image]

However, the page numbering is not appearing on the rest of the pages (see below):

[image]

Worst is the footer seems to be stuck at section 3, not counting the 4th page nor giving me enough space to put a page number.

The last pages are the same:

[image]

Final result is this:

[image]

Any tips / insights are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Why my footer page is appearing on the first one and not the others**

It seems you need to ensure that you link the footers to the previous page and that you have that option enabled.

[**Insert Headers and Footers**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-headers-and-footers-f22334fb-4455-4b18-9354-7c9c70c3b032)

> **Use the same header or footer across section boundaries**
>
> In a document where the header or footer varies by section, you can
>   make the header or footer the same across section boundaries.
>
> 1. Double-click the header or footer that you want to preserve across
>      section boundaries.
> 2. On the **Headers & Footers** tab, in the **Navigation** group, click **Next
>      Section** Button.
> 3. Click **Link to Previous** Button.
> 4. Office Word 2007 will ask if you want to delete the header and footer
>      and connect to the header and footer in the previous section. Click
>      Yes.

Comment: Hi @1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish spot on matey! Many thanks!

Comment: have a look matey ;)